# Как сделать, чтобы текст в списке подчеркивался? Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

Мой вариант:
[Без подчеркивания](http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=efffa3eff7236e729afd791c8209108d)

Необходимый результат:
[С подчеркиванием](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-MiTzuLUj__U/Ua8tABu0S9I/AAAAAAAATGE/wwoDqqlTPXE/s1600/Counter.png)

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что Вы показали называется разделитель (divider), исправьте в разметке ListView его параметры:

```
<ListView

    <!-- divider  -->
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >

</ListView>
```

Вместо цвета можно использовать drawable - ресурс.